# Converting ICE files to C++ using ICEBuilder

Tags: c++, ice

I am new to Slice/ICE files conversion to C++ and C#. I have installed ZEROC->ICE 3.5.1 on my computer and I am currently using Vistual Studio 2013 for these file conversion.

I have a bunch of .ice files that I want to convert to C++. The Ice Configuration box has the following files currently set up:         "--underscore -DSCONS_ICE_BUILD". With the current setting the Visual Studio generates C# files and not C++ files. Can someone please help me in figuring out what should be the fields for generating C++ files. Thanks in Advance!

Just to add I am using Ice-3.5.1 Visual Studio Add-in for C# file generation. Is there a separate addin for generating C++ file?

Comment: Just to add I am using Ice-3.5.1 Visual Studio Add-in for C# file generation. Is there a separate addin for generating C++ file ?

Answer (score 1):

Specifics for using the VS Marketplace add-in can be found [here](https://github.com/zeroc-ice/ice-builder-visualstudio/blob/master/README.md#c-usage). It appears that the VS adding handles both C++ and C#, but you must include the correct NuGet Package in your project. I'm not sure what Ice Configuration box you are referring to, but unless you are building with SCONS, you likely don't need that flag.

Did you make sure to choose C++ Project not C# when you created your solution and added ICEBuilder to it?

---

The following explains the process of generating C++ from slices without the VS add-in:

In order to generate C++ code for ICE slices, you need to use the `slice2cpp` program included with the ICE distribution. If you are using Visual Studio for build system, [the documentation suggests you install the distribution using NuGet](https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/3.7/release-notes/using-the-windows-binary-distributions#id-.UsingtheWindowsBinaryDistributionsv3.7-InformationforC++Developers):

> Once you've installed the Ice NuGet package into a C++ project as shown earlier, this project will find automatically all Ice C++ header files and import libraries. If you add zeroc.icebuilder.msbuild to this C++ project, Ice Builder will take care of compiling the Slice files in this project with slice2cpp (it uses the slice2cpp installed from the NuGet package).
>
> Moreover, the Debugger Path is set and you can run your application directly from Visual Studio - there is no need to set any additional environment variables.

If you cannot use the NuGet Package, you can find the ice builder distribution on [ZeroC's GitHub](https://github.com/zeroc-ice/ice-builder-msbuild#installation).

If you require using `slice2cpp` outside of the Visual Studio environment, (if you're using CMake as a build system from the command line, for example) the documentation states, you will need to add ICE's bin/ folder to your `PATH`.

Specifics on using `slice2cpp` from command line can be found [here](https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/3.7/language-mappings/c++11-mapping/slice2cpp-command-line-options).

Comment: Thanks @Cinder Biscuits, your post was very helpful. I could generate the cpp files from ICE files in my project. Just wanted to check if it is also possible to generate .lib file, so that I can use the functions present in C++ files generated in some other library ?  I tried specifying Configuration Properties-> General-> Target Extension to .dll and Configuration Type to Dynamic Library (.dll) on the properties window but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: To do that, you may have to fall back to `slice2cpp` on the commandline and use the `--dll-export MACRO` flag: https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/3.6/language-mappings/c++-mapping/slice2cpp-command-line-options#id-.slice2cppCommand-LineOptionsv3.6---dll-exportMACRO

Comment: It looks like the Project Setting inside the VS extension is called "Macro for exporting symbols from DLL"

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cinder Biscuits, I could find the "Macro for exporting symbol from DLL" option in Ice Configuration (I am building it via Ice Addin). Do you know what field I have to enter in this box for exporting the dll. I tried  1. --dll-export WIDGET_API 2. --dll-export 3. __declspec(dllexport), but that doesn't seem to be working. Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: I think you will just enter the name you've chosen for your exports. It would be `WIDGET_API`. It could be `ICE_API`. It could be `ICE_ICE_BABY`. That's entirely up to you, but you only need enter the macro name there.

`slice2cpp` will then generate __declspec definitions with that name + `_EXPORT`